# Migrate .Net Standard 2.0 to .Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-standard

I am working in an Web API project build using .Net Core 2.2. A couple of libraries were develop using .Net Standard 2.0. This is causing some incompatibilities issues with new .Net Core 2.2 libraries.

[image]

Is there a way to reference between those two .Net Standard libraries and .Net Core ones?

Or how to convert/ migrate from .Net Standard libraries and .Net Core ones?

Comment: According to [this table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) you should be fine to reference .NET Standard 2.0 libraries in a .NET Core 2.x project. But I don't think you can do it the other way round.

Comment: As an aside: IF your libraries are for internal use only AND they are only to be consumed by .NET Core projects, you'll have an easier life if your libraries target .NET Core too. Of course if either of those constraints don't apply, .NET Standard is the way to go and you should disregard the preceding :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of your project is targeted to .NET Core 2.2, and it is being used by other project that has .NET Standard 2.0 target. Please check the target of those projects.

Any .NET Core 2.2 project can't be used or referenced by .NET Standard projects. It should not be like this and I'm sure you have these incorrect reference conditions.

The correct reference "flow" is this: any .NET Standard projects can be referenced by any .NET Core 2.x projects. And this is not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't .NET Standard created to be a bridge between .NET Framework and .NET Core? So you can reference .NET Standard library directly from .NET Core.